# How do I get the drive light on my legacy floppy drive to turn off so I can remove the diskette?

Tags: 14.04, floppy

When I insert the floppy and click on 'Floppy Disk' in the list of 'Devices' in Nautilus, the drive light comes ON and I have no problem accessing the diskette.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Mobo: Asus P5GC-MX/1333 (circa 2007)
Desktop: GNOME

- using the on-board floppy controller

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Isn't there an eject icon next to the drive name, in the left-hand sidebar in Nautilus? Or a right-click menu item like "unmount" or "eject"?